# (Excel) Plotting data series and a subset of that series on one chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have a data series associated with text labels. I'm trying to fit a line to the second half of my data. I read that in order to do so I have to make a second data series consisting of the subset of data that I wish to plot.

However if I try to add new data series (the second half of the original series), Excel puts them at the beginning of my chart. The "horizontal axis labels" are just numbers 1-6 (the original data series has the list text labels, for simplicity's sake let's say A-L). However if I try to add a subset of my labels to the second series (say: G-L), Excel changes the labels in the original series as well. And so my plots are still misaligned, and now labeled G-L, instead of A-L.

Can you suggest me a workaround on any of my steps?

EDIT: Here are screenshots to illustrate my problem (sorry for the polish language, I hope everything is clear). I should note that in my original problem I use dates instead of labels A-K. These are just for the sake of simplicity.

The data and the plot, before adding anything for the fit:
[image: The data and the plot, before adding anything for the fit]

Here I add the second half of my data as a second data series for the plot:

[image: Here I add the second half of my data as a second data series for the plot!]

And this is the result of trying to add the labels G-K to the second series:

[image: And this is the result of trying to add the labels G-K to the second series]

Comment: I think easiest way would be do duplicate your data already in the source (only the part for what you need to fit the line) and insert the chart after. Have you tried it already?

Comment: What type of chart are you using, a scatter?

Could you provide a screenshot or text mockup of the arrangement of data currently?  Am I to understand it is 2 separate tables with text column headers with 1 row of numerical data underneath.

Comment: As a separate thing, I can't quite understand why you would need to fit a line to data with a non numerical x axis.  Text labels normally indicate categories, unless is it something like dates etc.?   (I'm asking because this might make for an easy solution not just to be snarky btw)

Comment: @MátéJuhász I'm afraid I don't understand, I'm not very handy with Excel charts. Could you please explain what you are suggesting exactly?

Comment: @Some_Guy I added the screenshots. Yes, the text data are in fact dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the picture below how you can split your data. Also I've applied a date horizontal axis to make regression sense.
[image]

Comment: Thanks this works! Although I'm mildly annoyed that this works automatically like above, but there seems to be no simple way of adding the second series later on. Excel charts to have a lot of great ways to automatically create charts, but not a lot of ways to "manually" tinker with them.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is actually dates, if you enter the date as a "date" then excel will reconise it as ascending numerical (after all, dates are numbers) rather than arbitrary text (which for all excel knows could be "cat", "dog", "banana" which doesn't make sense for a line graph.  Why should "cat" come before "dog" or vice versa?

You only have to do 2 if they're regular intervals, then you can autofill (read here https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-list-of-sequential-dates-aa1c0fa7-c76a-4762-8bc9-46f1691defec if unsure what this is, super easy)

Before: [image]

After:
[image]

Screenshots of process:

Excel updates the chart automatically if you change the date format.

Format ranges as dates by right click:

[image]
[image]

Then retype dates (in the format you selected). Remember, autofill